# "Too many open files" on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i have a cluster ES and from 2 days ago i have this error:

```
[2016-03-14 15:08:48,342][WARN ][cluster.action.shard] [node-01] [logstash-2016.03.14][2] received shard failed for [logstash-2016.03.14][2], node[72oHnFiXTVqgXaUYKTAu2Q], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [AKybrAEZRXebyRxcmzTqJQ], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[logstash-2016.03.14][2] failed recovery]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[[logstash-2016.03.14][2] failed to open reader on writer]; nested: FileSystemException[/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2016.03.14/2/index/_lg_Lucene410_0.dvm: Too many open files]; ]]
```

If i run `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?os=true&process=true&pretty=true' | grep "max_file_descriptors"` i have this output:

```
"max_file_descriptors" : 65535,
"max_file_descriptors" : 65535,
```

To the file /etc/security/limit.conf i already have:

```
elasticsearch - nofile 65535
elasticsearch - memlock unlimited
```

If i check the status of index i have some index RED....consequently logstash goes wrong and crashes all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set elasticsearch - nofile to unlimited.
And make sure you running with the right user.

Comment: It shouldn't run as root. How do you start the process? Anyway you can change limits of the root user to temporary solve it.

Comment: From root, "service elasticserach start", but the ulimit value for root is 1024, i have changed this value to 65535 with "ulimit -n 65535". Now think i need only restart ES to resolve, or start ES from elasticsearch user

Comment: There is runas property in /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: RUN_AS_USER=elasticsearch... And change the limit to unlimited, you already reached 65k.

Comment: ES currently run with elasticsearch user...is set to `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`, so i have to set `unlimited` to /etc/security/limits.conf?

Comment: Try to change it to 512000 in limits.conf. You can also use * instead of user name so it will work for all users.